# How do I add class to the next li element and remove it form others?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a class to the first list item on click of an anchor link. This first link, will not have the class of active onload.Then after that, onclick of the next  tag add the class of active to the next list item. However, it is selecting all list items and adding the class of active.

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>

<a class="btn-solid next">NEXT</a>

$('.next').on('click', function() {
    $('ul li').next('li').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: what you want exact ?? share your full code and explain proper what you need??

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following (comments in code)

1. update html so it starts with an active element
2. get current active li
3. check if active is last in list
4. if it is make first active, if not make next active

```js
$('.next').on('click', function() {
  var currentActive = $('li.active'); // get current active
  currentActive.removeClass('active'); // remove class active

  if (currentActive.is(':last-child')) {
    $('li').first().addClass('active'); // add class to first li if last child
  } else {
    currentActive.next('li').addClass('active'); // otherwise add active to next li
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="active">start one li off as active otherwise the below won't work</li>
  <li>some stuff</li>
  <li>some stuff</li>
</ul>

<a class="btn-solid next">NEXT</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping the index in a variable:

```
var idx = 0;
var lis = $('ul').children();

$('.next').on('click', function(){
    if (idx + 1 === lis.length){
        idx = 0;
    } else {
        idx++;
    }

    for  (i = 0; i < lis.length; i++){
        if (i === idx){
            lis[i].addClass('active');
        } else {
            lis[i].removeClass('active');
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look:

```
$('.next').on('click', function() {
    var $activeEl = null;
    if($('ul li.active').length){
       //get the active element
       $activeEl = $('ul li.active');
    }
       //remove the active class 
       $('ul li').removeClass('active');

       if($activeEl != null) // set the active class to the first element
          $('ul li:nth-child(1)').addClass('active');
       else        //set the active class to the next one
          $activeEl.next('li').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Please check the following code and output I guess it will help you.

```js
    $('.next').on('click', function() {
  var activeClass = $('li.active');
  if (activeClass.is(':last-child')) {
    $('li').first().addClass('active');
    $('li').last().removeClass('active');
  }
  else {
    $('ul li.active').next('li').addClass('active');
    $('ul li.active').prev('li').removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: #0000ff;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="active">one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>

<a href="#" class="btn-solid next">NEXT</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `eq` with `length` using `if` condition like below.

```js
$('body').on('click', '.next', function() {
  if ($('ul li.active').length == 0)
    $('ul li').eq(0).addClass('active');
  else
    $('ul li.active').removeClass('active').next('li').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>

<a href='#' class="btn-solid next">NEXT</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery class selector to get current active li, modify it using removeClass and modify next li using addClass.

```
$('.next').on('click', function() {
    $('ul li.active').removeClass('active').next('li').addClass('active');
});
```